# C#, manipulate user input on the fly console app

Tags: c#, console

I would like to be able to manipulate user input in a console application on the fly.
While the user enters text I would like to check the string the user enters, char by char while the user enters.

What I'm trying to accomplish is while the user enters an IP address, while the user is entering an octet, if the octet reaches 3 chars long, a period is added and the user can enter the next octet. If the octet is not 3 char long the user must enter the period manually. When the user is done entering the IP address the user must push enter to commit the IP address to the application.

Is this at all possible to achieve?

Best regards
Steffen

Comment: Take a look at `Console.ReadKey` (https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=net-7.0). Combine it with a loop and you should be able to implement it.

Comment: A full solution might have a bit more complexity than you've described. Are you trying to sanity-check the entered date as you go? For instance, if the user types 'z', that's not an allowable character. Or if the user types, say, "99", there is no valid third character at all, and presumably that's a complete octet needing a dot next rather than a digit. Also, what are you expecting to do if the user hits backspace, or the left arrow key?